# Where are Cinnamon Desktop Themes Stored?

Tags: themes, cinnamon

## Background

I have Ubuntu 16.04, with Cinnamon 3.2.2 Desktop.

I am trying to install a new theme inside Cinnamon. In the Settings panel, I find themes, but when I try to install them I get a 404 error:

[image]

I tried looking up the themes online from the "More Info" link, and I can download a zip file. However, I don't know where to put it.

## Question

Where do I put the themes that I have downloaded?

Comment: The above has the answer to my question. The title of that question isn't the same though, so having this question with link might help others find the answer.